# Sharing data between components in Angular: do we always need Observables?

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular and I am trying to figure out what the best / correct technics are to share data between components with no direct parent / child relationship.

There is already a lot of questions around this topic but they all point towards Observables / rxjs / subjects, etc.

However, in my test app I simply created a service that holds a value and 2 components. In component A, you can update the value defined in the service. Component B reads this value and hence gets the updated value. It works fine as the 2 components get the right value.

There is certainly something I did not grasp yet around the benefits of using those Observables.

Appreciate any insight on this.

Comment: without an observable, you would have to check constantly to see whether component A updated the value or not would't you?

Comment: There's not much to say. If you don't need the features that come with Observables or Subjects, don't use them. Most people use them because of the features they add (tracking, notification of updates, etc.). But if all you are about is setting a value and reading a value, and a service does the job, you're good.

Comment: Thanks guys. I am rather trying to understand the limitations I will face going simply via a service. Above was just an example, but are you saying that without Observables, Component B would not aware that the value in the service changed and hence would remain desynchronized from Component A until I take an action? Instead, with Observables, Component B would be notified that the value in the Service changed and hence would be updated automatically?

Comment: Well, you have a couple of choices there. You could conceivably use an `EventEmitter` to raise an event when the value changes in your service. So Component A would set the value, your service would raise a "valueChanged" event, Component B would have subscribed to that event and would receive the notification that way. However, that's a fair amount of code to write just to avoid using an Observable, which bundles all of that rigmarole in one object.

Comment: Because RXJS is more important than Angular.

Comment: Thanks Heretic Monkey ! That makes things clearer. One last thing: would I have to set an Observable for each single value I need to pass between components? Let's imagine I have a form on one component with several values input by the user and I want to display them (with some computations on top, like adding 2 values, etc.) in the other component.

Answer (score 1):

Heretic Monkey is correct but let me show you how easy it is to implement an observable.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyState { // I call this file a 'state' instead of a service because it does not get injected the same way
  // don't use any there should be a valid type. I'm initializing my any type to null for this example but IRL I wouldn't do that unless it makes sense.
  private readonly _value = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
  // a behavior subject is a subject that starts with an initial value and will emit any changes to that value instantly to any component hooked to it. it's the easiest one to use.
  public readonly $value = this._value.asObservable();

  // this is a getter so you can get a 1 time view of what it is set to (right now it's null)
  public get value$() {
    return this._value.getValue();
  }

  // this allow you to change or mutate your observable and emit that change to your subscribers
  public set value$(val: any) {
    this._value.next(val);
  }
```

That's how you implement the service/state whatever you prefer to call it.

In your component you can use the ngOnInit life cycle hook to subscribe to it like so:

```
constructor(private state: MyState) {}

private initSubscriptions(): void {
  this.state.$value.subscribe((val) => {
    this.yourComponentValue = val;
});
```

You can update your value in the component like so:

```
this.state.value$ = newValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

Service

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    
@Injectable()
export class AppService {
    constructor() {}
    
    name: String;
    
    getVale() {
        return (this.name = 'This is my service data');
    }
}
```

component where using service

```js
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
    
import { AppService } from './app.service';
    
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: './hello.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./hello.component.css']
})
export class HelloComponent {
    constructor(private app_service: AppService) {}

    name: String;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.name = this.app_service.getVale();
        console.log(name)
    }
}
```